# Concatenate variable names in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my wp7 application I do a web request that returns a status code like 100, 110, etc. Each status code is associated with a status message. This status messages are localized in my application.

E.g.

```
m100 'OK'
m110 'Text was empty'
```

I want to show this text in a message box like this. `contents` gives us the status code as string value.

```
var s = 
    MessageBox.Show(AppResources.m100, AppResources.Notice, MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

But I don't want to specify a message box for each message. I want to handle this in a dynamic way like this.

```
var s = 
    MessageBox.Show(AppResources.m+contents, AppResources.Notice, 
                    MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Instead of trying to access the name of the variable, you can try to use a Dictionnay like structure (or hashmap, hashtable, etc..) to store the messages and use m100, m110... as a key to access them.
That way you will have your message by doing: `myDictionnary.get(M100)`

Comment: @olchauvin, I think the `AppResources` class is generated from a resource file, so the dictionary is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) to get the value:

```
AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("m" + contents)
```